# Using a global function to identify which subfunctions to run

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a dataset with a categorical variable that may take around 6 or 7 unique variables.  Depending upon which variable that is, I need to run several functions - each of which is different depending upon the value of the categorical variable.

I don't know how to go about programming this so that things are called correctly.  Keep in mind this might be simple here, but in my scenario is much more complicated with lots of sub functions.

```
    library(dplyr)
    func1_value_one = function(multiplication_value){
    mtcars$check="value_one"
    mtcars$mpg =mtcars*multiplication_value
    filter(mtcars, mpg>60)
      }

   func0_value_zero = function(division_value){
    mtcars$check="value_zero"
    mtcars$mpg =mtcars$mpg / division_value
    filter(mtcars, mpg <3)
      }


       help_function=function(category_p,change_p){
        mtcars=return(filter(mtcars, vs==category_p))
            data=ifelse(category_p==0,return(func0_value_zero(change_p)),return(func1_value_            one(change_p)  ))
        return(data)
         }

 #i want to filter for the values that meet the parameter passed in and then perform the update on the values
 # right now I am not able to both filter for the values and then perform the correct function call.

       help_function(0,2)
```

so 
identifying_func(0,20) would return only only the rows from mtcars that has VS==0, divide all the mpg values by 20, and create a new column called check with all values equal to 'value_zero'

In the broader context, my dataset would use a flag to determine many different table join combinations and depending upon the data perform a variety of calculations and adjustments.

Comment: why doesn't your if-else approach work?

Comment: I am not able to receive the results needed.  I am trying to perform multiple steps in the process since the first function needs to 'pick' which sub-functions to run.  In the real world these wouldn't be simple division but would be large table joins and many sub-activities so I need make sure this works correctly. I updated with an example of what I was actually running.

Comment: you can't use `ifelse` here, that returns a vector the same length as `category_p==0` also, are those functions from a package

Comment: Yes, sorry i was using Dplyr.  Depending upon what I place first i can either get all the rows where vs==0 or perform the calculations upon the dataset by dividing by 2 and adding the additional colulmn.  But I can't get both things to work.